# How can I use a for loop to curl multiple urls in bash script?

Tags: bash, curl

I trying to curl this url for all 7 pages of reviews, and then store the reviews in a text file:
https://www.amazon.com/Ferrero-Rocher-Hazelnut-Chocolates-Count/product-reviews/B0042TVKZY/ref=cm_cr_getr_d_paging_btm_7?ie=UTF8&filterByStar=three_star&reviewerType=avp_only_reviews&pageNumber=7#reviews-filter-bar

This is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..7}

    do
        URL=$(curl "https://www.amazon.com/Ferrero-Rocher-Hazelnut-Chocolates-Count/product-reviews/B0042TVKZY/ref=cm_cr_getr_d_paging_btm_7?ie=UTF8&filterByStar=three_star&reviewerType=avp_only_reviews&pageNumber=3D${i}#reviews-filter-bar")
        RETURN=$(echo $URL)
        curl $RETURN >reviews${i}.text




    done
```

Comment: Is this a how to question or you have a problem ?

Comment: More of a how to question.

Comment: Did you find your answer ? If not can you clarify your issue.